# move to next column in excel

Tags: c#, excel

I am trying to fill an excel sheet from a windows form and database using C#

I am generating a list of names and want to put each name in Row 1 starting with Column A and keep doing this until the list is empty.
The code below is what I have used previously for moving down rows but I can't seem to get anything working for moving across Columns.

```
ws.get_Range("A"+ row.ToString()).Value2 = lastPlf.AddDays(90).ToString("dd MMM yy");
```

Can anyone help me get this to change column rather than row?

Comment: use sth like this `ws.get_Range("A1").Offset(0,col).Value2 = ...`

Comment: You'll find it easier to use `Cells` than `get_Range`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like to use

```
  currentColumn = 1, currentRow = 2
  For i=1 To 10 
     Cells(currentRow, currentCoulmn).Value = "foo"
     ' or 
     Sheets(2).Cells(currentRow, currentCoulmn).Value = "bar"
     currentColumn = currentColumn +1
  Next
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
ws.Rows[1].Columns[row].Value2 = lastPlf.AddDays(90).ToString("dd MMM yy");
```

Or

```
ws.Cells[1, row].Value2 = lastPlf.AddDays(90).ToString("dd MMM yy");
```